# Problem with casting BigDecimal to int in oracle sql query

Tags: java, sql

I have a problem with casting BigDecimal to int in sql query:

```
SELECT new someDTO(l.name, NVL(table1.amount, table2.BigDecimalAmount))
FROM.....
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT new someDTO(l.name, CAST(NVL(table1.amount, table2.BigDecimalAmount) AS int))
```

and I received `QuerySyntaxException`. Please help.

Comment: delete "new" ...

Comment: new is nessecary.

Comment: Problem is with CAST I think. Maybe someone has diffrent way to recieve int from BigDecimal. I can't use Integer.valueOf  and .intValue() in this place.

Comment: no it is not, it cant be used in SQL, And bigDecimal isnt a type in SQL but in JAVA, you got this two languages confused. Casting BigDecimal to int isnt done in SQL but in JAVA

Comment: Maybe `BigDecimalAmount` is just a column name.  If so, what datatype is it. Otherwise I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: @OracleDev yes, but I'm using JPA and EntityManager in IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found correct form:

SELECT new someDTO(l.name, NVL(table1.amount, CAST (table2.BigDecimalAmount AS int))).